# jquery post internal server error

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, post

```
    $('.active-teacher').click(function() {
       $.post('<?php echo base_url('authsm8csk/change_teacher'); ?>/'+this.id);
    });
```

when i execute this url by typing in the web browser, the code in controller is running, so i think that the code in controller is no problems. but when i running in via clicking the element with 'active-teacher' class. internal server error 500. please help me.

the error show like this in chrome development console, sorry i can't post an image

POST http://domain.com/sman8kab/authsm8csk/change_teacher/3 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: If you are receiving a 500 error then the problem is on the server side.

Comment: Can you show your PHP Code?

Comment: public function change_teacher($id) {
        $query=  $this->m_teacher->get_id($id);
        $row=$query->row();
        if($row->status==1) {
            $data=array('status'=>0);
        } else {
            $data=array('status'=>1);
        }
        $this->m_teacher->update($id,$data);
    }

Comment: but when i try the url by typing in the browser, it's running well

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP syntax is wrong. You are closing the PHP brackets early thus leading to syntax error. Correct should be

`$.post("<?php echo base_url('authsm8csk/change_teacher'); ?>/"+this.id);`

Comment: I have try this way, but the same error showing. thanks for your attention.

Comment: try this `$.post("<?php echo base_url('authsm8csk/change_teacher/'); ?>"+this.id)`

Comment: if i type code like that, the url  like this http://localhost:8080/sman8kab/authsm8csk/change_teacher3 and also always error. but thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fix this problem, the internal server error because the post action doesn't allowed by csrf protection, so I adding the csrf token to post data, here is my updated code:

```
$('.active-teacher').click(function() {
    var id=this.id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url('authsm8csk/change_teacher'); ?>/"+id,
        data: {"<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>":"<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>"}
    });
});
```